# Rails Controller Testing: ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I’m teaching myself to write controller tests and am getting this getting this error:

```
ERROR["test_should_update_post", PostsControllerTest, 2015-10-11 12:12:31 -0400]
 test_should_update_post#PostsControllerTest (1444579951.69s)
ActionController::UrlGenerationError:         ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"posts", :post=>{:title=>"My Post", :body=>"Updated Ipsum"}}
            test/controllers/posts_controller_test.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in <class:PostsControllerTest>'
            test/controllers/posts_controller_test.rb:50:in `block in <class:PostsControllerTest>’
```

This is my test:

```
test "should update post" do 
  assert_difference('Post.count') do 
    put :update, post: {title: 'My Post', body: 'Updated Ipsum'}
  end

  assert_redirected_to post_path(assigns(:post))
end
```

this is my yaml:

```
entry_one:
  title: "Foobar"
  body: "Ipsum This"

entry_two:
  title: "Barfoo"
  body: "This Ipsum"
```

and this is my controller:

```
def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    if @post.update(post_params)
        redirect_to @post, notice: 'Event updated successfully'
    else
        render :edit
    end
end
```

Can you point me towards the problem I need to solve?

I can tell from the error and the line count that it’s something to do with the lines:
`assert_difference('Post.count') do` and `put :update, post: {title: 'My Post', body: 'Updated Ipsum’}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an `id` to the `update` action:

`put :update, id: <THE ID HERE>, post: {title: 'My Post', body: 'Updated Ipsum'}`

Comment: Thanks so much. I passed my fixture in `<THE ID HERE>` as `@post.id`. That solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to your `update` action in your controller, you need to pass an `id` of the `post` in your `params`.

So, in your test, build your `params` hash like this:

```
let(:update_query_parameters) { { post: { title: 'My Post', body: 'Updated Ipsum' }, id: post.id } }
```

Then, use `update_query_parameters` to pass as `params` for your `put :update` method:

```
test "should update post" do
  assert_difference('Post.count') do
    put :update, update_query_parameters
  end

  assert_redirected_to post_path(assigns(:post))
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I wasn't passing an id. I had no idea of the problem I needed solve before your help and that of the other commenter. I didn't use your process, but I certainly focused on the right problem thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to two the commenters above, I was able to understand the problem I needed to solve: That I need to pass an id in my update test.

I'd already done this in a similar edit test for the same app, i knew exactly what to try.

I'd previously used a setup method in my test to pass my yaml shared above into my tests:

```
def setup
   @post = posts(:entry_one)
end
```

With this method I can pass @post.id into my update test and get it to pass as such:

```
test "should update post" do 
  assert_no_difference('Post.count') do 
    put :update, id: @post.id, post: {title: 'My Post', body: 'Updated Ipsum'}
  end

  assert_redirected_to post_path(assigns(:post))
end
```